# How would I use an Artificial Intelligence algorithm to a program for it to learn and assign appropriate weight values?

Tags: python, algorithm, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I have a program I am writing and I am wondering how I would use some AI algorithm for my program so that it can learn and assign appropriate weight values to my fields.

For example I have fields a, b, c, d, and e. Each of these fields would have different weights because field a is more valuable than d. I was wondering how I would go about doing this so I can normalize my values and use a sum of these values to compare.

Example:

```
Weight of a = 1
Weight of b = 2
Weight of c = 3
Weight of d = 4
Weight of e = 5
```

For the sum, multiply each field's value with its assigned weight:

```
Result = (value of a) * 1 + (value of b) * 2 + (value of c) * 3 + (value of d) * 4 + (value of e) * 5
```

I am looking to input some training data and train my program to learn and compare the a,b,c,d,e values possessed by each object so that it can assign weights to each one.

EDIT: I am just looking for the method to approach this, whether it be by using neural nets, or some other means to learn and assign weights to these fields.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems have you encountered? What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this depends a lot on what kind of a program you're writing. How do you assess how good of an answer `result` is?

If `result` can either be correct or incorrect in a categorical way, then a **neural net** would be a great option. You could use a two-layer topology (i.e. all of the input nodes are connected to each output node, with no layer in between), and have each input node correspond to one of your fields (a, b, c, etc.). You can then use backpropagation to train the network such that each set of field values maps to the correct category. The edge weights that you end up with at the end will be the weights to associate with each field.

However, if `result` can either be either more or less accurate in some sort of a continuous way, a **genetic algorithm** is probably a better solution. This could be the case if you're comparing `result` to some ideal value, if you're using the weights in some sort of function with an evaluatable outcome (like a game), or some other similar situation. The fitness function that you use will depend on your exact circumstances (for the examples above you might use proximity to the ideal value, or win-loss ratio when playing the game with those values). There are a variety of ways that you could format the candidate solutions:

- One option would be to use a sequence of bitstrings representing each weight in binary. Mutations could flip any bit and crossover could occur at any point along the string (or you could only allow it to occur between numbers)
- If you want to allow for floating point values, though, you might be
  better off using a system where each candidate solution is a list of weights. Mutations can add or subtract from a given weight an crossover can occur at any point within the list.

If you want to provide more information on what specifically your program is trying to accomplish, I can try to offer a more specific suggestion.

Comment: First off, thank you for your great response! This is for a simple fantasy sports simulator/aid. Each stat possessed by the player would have a weight and multiplying all these weight and stat values together (for example: Points * 0.5 + Rebounds * 1 + etc) would result in an end value that we would be able to use to compare it with other other players. The problem is I do not know where to begin in determining these weights so I looked for an AI algorithm that would help me accomplish this to assign the weights accordingly (whether by historical data, averages, etc). Thank you!

Comment: If you have a way to automatically assess how good the set of rankings produced by a set of weights are, then it sounds like a genetic algorithm is your best bet. 

Although if there is some sort of a historical statistic that you could use as a direct proxy for how good a given player was, it might be faster to just do a multi-variable regression to predict that statistic. The coefficients assigned to each variable would be your weights.